# SetupVerifyInfFile - The parameter is incorrect. How to use C# pinvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have problem with calling/implementing [SetupVerifyInfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupverifyinffilew).
When I call the `VerifyInfFile` function, I receive Exception "The parameter is incorrect".

```cs
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetupVerifyInfFile(
        string FileName,
        IntPtr AltPlatformInfo,
        ref IntPtr InfSignerInfo);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SP_INF_SIGNER_INFO
    {
        public int CbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string CatalogFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string DigitalSigner;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string DigitalSignerVersion;
    }

    public static void VerifyInfFile(string infPath)
    {
        SP_INF_SIGNER_INFO infSignerInfo = default;
        infSignerInfo.CbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(infSignerInfo);
        var infSignerPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(infSignerInfo.CbSize);

        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(infSignerInfo, infSignerPtr, false);
            if (!SetupVerifyInfFile(infPath, IntPtr.Zero, ref infSignerPtr))
                throw new Exception("Error calling SetupVerifyInfFile().", new 
                                     Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(infSignerPtr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf(Object)` is obsolete. What happens when you use `Marshal.SizeOf<SP_INF_SIGNER_INFO>()` instead?

Comment: I checked this and I get the same error. I'm not sure if I implemented INF_SIGNER_INFO structure or SetupVerifyInfFile method 100% well.

Comment: If the parameters *were* correct, such an exception would not be expected. That is: the assertion/assumption is likely incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four obvious mistakes that I can see:

1. The third parameter you pass as `ref IntPtr InfSignerInfo`. It is a mistake to pass this as `ref`. As documented, this parameter is a pointer to the struct. So you need to remove the `ref`.
2. You don't specify a character set for `SP_INF_SIGNER_INFO` and so will get the default character set which is ANSI. That doesn't match `CharSet.Auto` in your function declaration.
3. You use the wrong value for `CbSize`. You provide the size of a pointer, but you need to provide the size of the structure, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_INF_SIGNER_INFO))`.
4. You have used an incorrect value for `MAX_PATH`. The correct value is 260, and not 256.

Comment: I deleted `ref` from `ref InfSignerInfo`. I also added `CharSet.Auto` to `SP_INF_SIGNER_INFO`. Now it looks like `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]`. The error still appears.

Comment: I did what you wrote in point 3, but unfortunately, the same error continues.

Comment: What might be more useful to you would be to learn how I debugged all of this. I created a trivial C++ program that does the same thing, and works. Inspection of the value of `CbSize` led me to point 4.